# Hide deprecation warnings

Tags: swift, xcode

I am deprecating large parts of a Swift library of mine, using the `@available` attribute, as such:

```swift
@available(*, deprecated, message: "This will be removed in 1.4.0.")
```

However, I only want to these deprecation warnings to be displayed for developers who use the library. I do not want the library project to display these warnings.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: The whole point of deprecation warnings is that they are displayed to users to let them know about the necessity of updating their code. I don't think what you're looking for is possible and it wouldn't make any sense either...

Comment: I think it makes sense if the library, which knows about the deprecation, can disable such warnings, since they are meant for the users.

Comment: @DanielSaidi, so you want warning to be not transitive?

Comment: In the _Build Settings_, in _Apple Clang - Warnings - All languages_, disabling the _Deprecated Functions_ key should do the magic, but it does not work for me. Maybe you could give it a try.

Comment: @user28434 I'm not sure what that means, but I just want to disable deprecation warnings for the library project...but that it is still enabled for other projects that import the library.

Comment: @ÁngelTéllez Yeah, I tried that as well but it doesn't work. The warnings still appear.